# Satellizer Twitter Login is showing a blank popup?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter, twitter-oauth, satellizer

I am running an angularjs satellizer based twitter login / sign-up
Here is my config :

```
$authProvider.twitter({
                clientId : config.twitterAppId,
                responseType : "token"
})
```

where `config.twitterAppId` is my Twitter `Owner ID`

I invoke the popup with

```
 $scope.Twitterlogin = function () {
            $auth.authenticate("twitter");
 };
```

Once I do that a blank popup is shown, there is no error shown. 
I have a backend that's mapped to the default `auth/twitter` url, hence why I missed it in the configuration code. 
I have zero idea how to even approach, any input will be much appriciated.

Regards,
Peter

Comment: I remember finding that twitter had deprecated this API but I could be wrong. This question poses an interest for me so I will be watching :)